# Tomcat jdbc connection pool changes in hot

Tags: java, tomcat, jdbc

Is there any way to change the pool connection of tomcat in hot, for example release a connection, or reduce the max connection without undeploying the app (if the data source is in the app) or stop tomcat (if the data source is in Tomcat)

Comment: Usually the datasources are defined ONCE so the logical connections (you got from the pool) reuse the very same socket (because creating it is expensive). So, those are initialized when the context is deployed (in the app) or in container startup (in tomcat config files). To reinstance those classes requires either context restart or container restart

Answer (score 0):

You can connect to your running app using JMX (e.g. using `jconsole`) and do some manipulation. This is actually what JMX was designed for.

The `jconsole` JMX path for the connection on my machine is `MBeans -> Catalina -> DataSource -> javax.sql.DataSource -> <my data source> -> Operations`

My current Tomcat allows remove/add connection properties, get and close connection. You can easily write an MBean which does what you need if this is not sufficient.

Answer (score -1):

Some enterprise containers such as WebLogic support your requirements, but as far as I know Tomcat does not.